# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) while checking app version

Tags: flutter

I want to check the latest app version in the google play store and update the app in case their is a new version available.
Below is the code for checking current version.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GetLatestAppVersion {
http.Client client = http.Client() ;

bool success;
String message;
String version;
String minAppVersion;
String about;

Future<void> call() async {
try {
  var response = await client.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=*********",
  );

  var result = jsonDecode(response.body);

  if (result['success'] != null) {
    success = result['success'];
    message = result['message'];

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      version = result["latestAppVersion"]["Version"];
      minAppVersion = result["latestAppVersion"]["MinAppVersion"];
      about = result["latestAppVersion"]["About"];
    }
    else
      print(response.statusCode);
  }
} catch(e)
print(e)
```

}
}

When I run this code, status code is coming as 200,but I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
[        ] E/flutter (  988): <!doctype html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head><base 
href="https://play.goo...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Because you're trying to decode html response. The url doesn't respond with JSON, it returns html contents

Comment: So what shall I do instead?

Comment: You seem to have a firm grasp what you *expect* the response to look like. Whoever told you that, go to that source and ask what you have to do to get that response.

Comment: @ShivanshiVerma instead you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update it checks for a new app update